# Duplicate CSS Output for (background)Colors in NuxtV3 Project

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've noticed duplicate CSS output for colors in my Nuxt V3 project with Tailwind CSS. For example, when using classes like text-red-400 and bg-primary, the generated CSS includes redundant declarations:

```
.text-red-400 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(248 113 113 / 1);
    color: rgb(248 113 113 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.bg-primary {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(22 36 71 / 1);
    background-color: rgb(22 36 71 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

Can somebody tell me why is this happening?

I did start a new Nuxt project. I only installed tailwindcss and kept all files as clean as possible. You can see those here:  https://prnt.sc/YiI8v2Ix_kOm

Here I made a simple app.vue file with the classes as writing above here as input, you can see this here: https://prnt.sc/YnsmVAbIr0T1

Comment: It seems like you have some build process that attempts to polyfill CSS variables somewhere, though you have not provided enough details for us to be able to say for sure.

Comment: Good point, I did update my question. Created a new project where I did kept all files as clean as possible, as you can see on this print screen: https://prnt.sc/YiI8v2Ix_kOm